# How to find each square in datamatrix code

Tags: python, c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

Im working on a project to grade 2d code like datamatrix using emgu/opencv and c#.
I want to be able to detect each outer square in the image. like shown below :

[image]

I tried to extract contours of the image, but i get the combined contour like shown below :

[image]

How to I extract only the outer squares for analysis?

UPDATE:

I used the outer edge bounding box rectangle and tried to split the image into 14 rows and columns, but for some reason it is smaller than the bounding box but has the correct rows and columns. Due to this i'm unable to extract the color from each of these cells. Here is my code

```
      CvInvoke.cvThreshold(grayimg, grayimg, 50, 255.0, THRESH.CV_THRESH_BINARY);
                    grayimg._Not();

                    StructuringElementEx element = new StructuringElementEx(3, 3, 1, 1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CV_ELEMENT_SHAPE.CV_SHAPE_RECT);
                    CvInvoke.cvMorphologyEx(grayimg, grayimg, IntPtr.Zero, element, CV_MORPH_OP.CV_MOP_CLOSE, 18);

                    var sourceContours1 = grayimg.FindContours(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_EXTERNAL);

                    Rectangle rr = CvInvoke.cvBoundingRect(sourceContours1, 3);
                 
                    int verticalGrids = 14;
                    int horizontalGrids = 14;

                    int gridWidth = rr.Width / 14;
                    int gridHeight = rr.Height / 14;

                    for (int j = 0; j < verticalGrids; j++)
                    {
                        int yo = j * gridHeight;

                        for (int k = 0; k < horizontalGrids; k++)

                        {
                            int xo = k * gridWidth;

                            Rectangle gridBox = new Rectangle(); ;
                            gridBox.X = rr.X + xo;
                            gridBox.Y = rr.Y + yo;
                            gridBox.Width = gridWidth;
                            gridBox.Height = gridHeight;

                            fullframegradcam3.Draw(gridBox, new Bgr(0, 255, 0), 2);

                        }

                    }

                    cibcam3.Image = fullframegradcam3.Bitmap;
```

And here is the output I get:
[image]

Comment: erode/dilate maybe

Comment: Direct extraction of these squares is difficult. Better try to get the global bounding square and from knowledge of the number of cells, estimate and extract slices containing only the squares. Then you may get them individually. Alternatively, detect the transverse edges in these slices.

Comment: @YvesDaoust  Please check the original question, I have updated it with what  you suggested, but not getting the proper output.

Answer (score 1):

A possibility is to estimate the inner area of the code and fill it to erase.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please check the original question, I have updated it with what you suggested, but not getting the proper output

Comment: @user3177511: original or preprocessed image ?

Comment: Presprocessed Image....i converted to grayscale >> threshold >> morph close